# React render weather icons over a image based on local fetched data

Tags: reactjs, imagemap

Hi I'm new in React development and I'm developing a React app with a Nestjs back-end for my company. The app will be hosted on local servers with no internet access, front-end users have not internet access neither. I'm looking forward to render a map (like the example image below) where in fixed cords of the map render a weather icon based on a weather forecast data fetched from my back-end.

[image]

I have been using https://github.com/img-mapper/react-img-mapper for another functionality in my app like this one but I don't think that with that library I can get the result I'm expecting because I can not render an icon over certain area, neither get all areas highlighted when the images first loads.

My question is if there is any third party library to get this result or how can I achieve this result hard coded.

Thanks in advance